# Unityで自作したVRをQuest2単体で実行できるようにしたい

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

初歩的な質問で恐縮です。
Unityで自作したVRをQuest2にビルドして、PCに繋がなくても単体でプレイするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。
自分で調べた限りでは「**SIDEQUEST**」というものを利用すれば可能とあったのですが、それは正規の方法なのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。